# Automate clean projects, build projects, clean tomcat, debug tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

In Eclipse I am trying to automate the following sequence:

1. Select couple of projects and run Clean (it triggers build too).
2. Select Tomcat (in eclipse) and run Clean.
3. Select Tomcat (in eclipse) and run Debug.

1,2,3 alone can take from 1 to 5 minutes. I get distracted and sometimes I even forgot what command I am running and have to start all over again.

Some kind of notification upon completion would be nice, too.

Comment: sounds like you mess around with symptoms? why is the clean everything necessary? Did you consider using hot code replacement tools like JRebel if things are a bit weird?

Comment: Symtomps - you are right. Clean everything - this is the process I've been told to use. I can not request JRebel at the moment.

Comment: I am FE dev who occasionally fights with this environment and every time the experience is frustrating. Thus I try to automate it.

Comment: well try a trial license, if it works and you save 1h per day... easy calculation. Have you tried something like https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/ ? if you can assign shortcuts to what you do or configure launch files to do what you need that may be possible (and creating that will take more time than a JRebel license :p - just a guess)